# Google Speech to Text does not return results

Tags: android, kotlin, google-speech-api

I want Google Speech to text API to recognize a short phrase after I press a button. So I came up with the following code. But it keeps returning no results. I'm quite confused, there are results in there (the buffer etc.), the mic is working well and is enabled in the emulator. Google console also doesn't show errors.

Here's my code.
Click listener that starts the recording:

```
val clicker: View.OnClickListener = View.OnClickListener {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting record thread")
        mAudioRecorder.record(LISTEN_TIME_MILLIS)
    }
    mReadButton.setOnClickListener(clicker)
```

Here's a broadcast receiver that processes the results and tries to send them to Google:

```
private val broadCastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(contxt: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent!!.getBooleanExtra(RECORDING_SUCCESS, false)) {
            val byteArrayExtra = intent.getByteArrayExtra(RECORDING_AUDIO)
            val audioResultByteString: ByteString = ByteString.copyFrom(byteArrayExtra)

            if (audioResultByteString.size() > 0) {
                val audio: RecognitionAudio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
                    .setContent(audioResultByteString).build()

                val resultsList = mSpeechClient.recognize(config, audio).resultsList

                if (resultsList.size > 0) {                       
                    for (result in resultsList) {
                        val resultText = result.alternativesList[0].transcript
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "- Done recognition. Result Qty: ${resultsList.size}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the AudioRecorder class function, which does the recording:

```
fun record(listenTimeMillis: Long) {
    val byteString: ByteString = ByteString.EMPTY
    mAudioRecorder = initAudioRecorder()
    val mBuffer = ByteArray(4 * AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE_HZ, CHANNEL, ENCODING))
    mAudioRecorder!!.startRecording()

    Thread {
        Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND)
        Thread.sleep(listenTimeMillis)

        val read = mAudioRecorder!!.read(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.size, AudioRecord.READ_NON_BLOCKING)
        val intent = Intent(RECORDING_COMPLETED_INTENT)
        try {
            if (read > 0) {
                intent.putExtra(RECORDING_AUDIO, mBuffer)
                intent.putExtra(RECORDING_SUCCESS, true)
            }

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.stackTrace.toString())
        }

        releaseAudioRecorder()
    }.start()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this. The thing to blame was a too small buffer size. So the recognition server was actually getting half a second of audio record which it obviously couldn't recognize.

```
 val mBuffer = ByteArray(4 * AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE_HZ, CHANNEL, ENCODING))
```

instead of 4 I put 200 and instead of `AudioRecord.READ_NON_BLOCKING` I have put `AudioRecord.READ_BLOCKING` and I read the buffer in a loop and increase the offset in each iteration. Then it started working.

```
val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        var deltaTime = 0L
        var offset = 0
        val intent = Intent(RECORDING_COMPLETED_INTENT)
        val readChunk = 512

        while (deltaTime < listenTimeMillis && offset < mBuffer.size) {
            val read = mAudioRecord!!.read(mBuffer, offset, readChunk, AudioRecord.READ_BLOCKING)

            if (read < 0) {
                intent.putExtra(RECORDING_SUCCESS, false)
                break; //if read with error, end here
            }

            deltaTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime //startTime is a while loop breaking condition so it lestens only for specified amount of time
            offset += readChunk
        }
```